# NSTableView - Pre-Hilight a certain row

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios, row

Hey all, I have a table where the user can select a preferred sound, but one should be already preselected.

I know the row number that should be preselected, however, I do not know the index number. How would I get that?

Cheers all, Merry Xmas.

Comment: What do you mean by `I know the row number .. do not know the index number`? What is your interpretation of `index number`?

Comment: The row number is a simple integer, that I obtained by going through the source array. I don't know how to convert that to an index number with which to animate the table view to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSIndexPath` class provides a handy method to provide the index for a given row and section: +[indexPathForRow:inSection:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSIndexPath/indexPathForRow%3ainSection%3a)

You could use it as follows:

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSUInteger)rowNum inTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNum
                                                 inSection:0];
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                           animated:YES
                     scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
}
```

Comment: That seems perfect, however I neglected to mention that I'm calling this from the delegate. Thus it gives me the may not respond to +indexPath:forRow: error.

Comment: Never mind, it worked, the problem was the [UITableView indexPathForRow... - The correct implementation is [IndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNum inSection:0];